# How to die Magento immediately when getting an exception?

Tags: magento

I got a problem when try to get a `helper`:

`Mage::helper('providers')`

In fact, the provider `helper` is not exist.

But it just out an exception and save it into the file: `var/log/exception.log` and everything is ok, except I could not see the interface which I want.

I need a way to do if I got any exception, Magento will exit immediately and show the messages on the browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turn on developer mode, and make sure PHP is showing errors.

Open up `index.php` and change this

```
if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
}

#ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

To this

```
#if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
#}

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

With developer mode on Exceptions will halt execution instead of being logged.

Also, you could skip comment the if block out by adding the apache environmental variable to `MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE` to your `.htaccess` file and setting it to 1.

Comment: I've tried your solution. It doesn't work as I want... I could understand that: because it's wrapped inside a `try-catch` block and just throw an exception. How can we exist if after throw the `Exception`?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: In htaccess the environment variable should be set like this?

`[E=MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE:1]`

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the call in a try catch block, i.e.

```
try {
  Mage::helper('providers');
}
catch (Exception $e){
  echo $e;
}
```